# Is it posible to programmatically search for players and create a match using gamekit

Tags: ios, user-interface, game-center, gamekit

I am trying to create my own user interface for match making instead of using game center. I can find friends programmatically, but I can't seem to figure out if it is possible to create a "search and request" ui just like wordfeud, where you enter a nickname, click search, and then send an invite if a player with that nickname exists of course.

Is it posible or do I have to use the native game center ui?

thanks :)

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1 try to follow this tutorial u may can get some idea here u should have client server...model